# IE 11 user agent string using asp.net 1.1

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, internet-explorer, iis

We have an old asp.net 1.1 application, which is currently running under IIS 5.2 and Windows Server 2003.  Our network group will be possibly moving us to IE 11, while testing we noticed some forms are broken.  Using IE 11 developers tool, the forms can be corrected if we change the user agent string to IE 9.

Is there anyway to do change the user agent to IE9 without changing the aspx.vb code?

We are looking into the possibility to upgrading to .net 4.5 to see if that resolves the problem.
http://blogs.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/posts/13-12-19/how-to-get-your-asp.net-application-working-in-ie11

```
<configuration>   <system.web>
<clientTarget>
 <add alias="ie9" userAgent="Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)" />
</clientTarget>    </system.web>  </configuration>
```

Comment: Have you looked into <browsercaps> in your web.config? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7271/Browser-Detection-using-ASP-NET

Comment: Another possibility here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17302050/compatibility-problems-with-internet-explorer-10-11-and-an-old-net-framework-1

Comment: @RickS Your suggestion worked, if you want to Answer is below I can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some searching on Stack Overflow and found this solution to your problem:

The solution was to follow [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff962563.aspx) MSDN article.

> You can retarget the application to run under .NET Framework 4. Retargeting requires that you add a element to the application's configuration file that allows it to run under .NET Framework 4

Referenced question here: [Compatibility problems with Internet Explorer 10/11 and an old .net framework 1.1 website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17302050/compatibility-problems-with-internet-explorer-10-11-and-an-old-net-framework-1)